# MongoDB - convert double to string with aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I am trying to convert double to string. I am not sure why my results are not as needed.

```
export function StoreSettings(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
  Setting.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { restaurantID: id }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        "appTheme.appBanner": {
          $concat: [
            "/App/Carousel/",
            { $toString: "$appTheme.appBanner" },
            ".png"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ])
    .exec()
    .then(data => {
      return res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => res.json({ data: "Data Not Found", err }));
}
```

==OUTPUT==

```
{
    "_id": "5e3379be06558d0c40d035ee",
    "appTheme": {
        "appBanner": "/App/Carousel/1.58078e+12.png"
    }}
```

=== i NEED it to be like this: ====

```
{
    "_id": "5e3379be06558d0c40d035ee",
    "appTheme": {
        "appBanner": "/App/Carousel/1580782209156.png"
}}
```

what am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give your input documents !!

Comment: this is the function, my issue is that the results are not String.
as you see i get this results 1.58078e+12.png
i need it as a string like this 1580782209156.png
thanks

Comment: If your aggregation is returning that then what do you've in `appTheme.appBanner` in your input docs ?

Comment: i have this value - 1580782209156, but as soon as i change it to "string" i get this value 1.58078e+12

Comment: what is the type of it ? Is that long ?? All you need is to convert it to string & append to a string ? As you've `$toString` would work on it if it's of type `NumberLong()`..

Comment: type is double, $toString change it to 1.58078e+12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `$appTheme.appBanner :1580782209156` is a double in database, then using `$toString` would result in `1.58078e+12`. You need to convert it into `NumberLong()` using `$toLong` & then convert it to string, Try below :

```
Setting.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { restaurantID: id }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "appTheme.appBanner": {
                $concat: [
                    "/App/Carousel/",
                    { $toString: { $toLong: "$appTheme.appBanner" } },
                    ".png"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nQk5wqkTrzS)